# nodejs with jquery and jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am building a website where I have an ADMIN page. There are multiple input fields. Im working with a `mongodb` database using `jade`. Here is the code for the users in jade:
         `ul.allUsersList
                each user, i in userlist
                    li.users
                        label Username: &nbsp;
                        span.usernameField #{user.username} &nbsp;
                        label Email: &nbsp;
                        span #{user.email} &nbsp;
                        label Points: &nbsp;
                        span #{user.points} &nbsp;
                        if user.luniConsecutivi >= 5
                            label.red Luni consec.: &nbsp;
                            span.red #{user.luniConsecutivi} &nbsp;
                        else 
                            label Luni consec.: &nbsp;
                            span #{user.luniConsecutivi} &nbsp;
                        label Telefon: &nbsp;
                        span 0#{user.phoneNo} &nbsp;
                        label Permissions: &nbsp;
                        span #{user.permissions} &nbsp;
                        label.reducere Reducere: &nbsp;
                        span.reducereValue #{user.reducere} RON`

There is the `.usernameField`. What Im trying to do is when the `.usernameField` is clicked I get that value from the `span` and add it to all the input fields (for easier use). Here is jQuery code:

```
`$(document).ready( () => {
    $('.usernameField').on('click', () => {
        let user = $(this).text();
        console.log(user);

        document.getElementById('incField').value = user;
        document.getElementById('decField').value = user;
        document.getElementById('removeField').value = user;
    })
});`
```

The problem is that in the jQuery code `user` is always an empty string. How can I get the `innerHTML` of the `li` that I click on correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use an arrow function but `function() { ... }` for the callback or use `evt.currentTarget` instead of `this` and `(evt) => { ... }`

Comment: Thank you a lot! Problem solved!